# Can we give each weak beat a weak degree from strong and weak beats notation?

Tags: rhythm, beats

I've seen the strong and weak beats written S-W-s-w in 4/4 time. This means strongest - weak - strong - the weakest. The distinction between the strengths of weak beats seems to be characteristic of this notation.

So what about in 2/4, 3/4 or 8/6 time? I thought of possibilities like S-W, S-W-w, S-W-W-s-W-w, but I don't know which one is the correct answer. I'm not even sure if the strongest and weakest are exactly one. Can we give each weak beat a weak degree in other beats?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Rhythm with Time Signatures](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/99112/understanding-rhythm-with-time-signatures)

Comment: There are many posts on this subject. Try searching [strong weak is:question](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=strong+weak+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Have you tried using M for medium? e.g. 6/8: S-w-w-M-w-w.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a comment that all these may change in various ways.

4/4   S-w-s-w
2/4   S-w
3/4   S-w-W (at least for waltzes) (also 3/8 or 3/16)
6/8   S-w-w-s-w-w (really 2/4 with triplets)